# SharePoint Designer 2007 crashes when connecting to a big list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

**Situation**

I have a site collection that has a lot of sub-sites. I am using SharePoint Designer 2007 to connect a large list from one site to another on a Data View Web  Part. It connects just fine and shows all of the lists, but when I click on 'Show Data,' it will wait for a long time and then crash.

**Question**

Do you know of a good way to modify the actual query that SharePoint Designer uses with the SharePoint database or add in a Data View Web Part without using the typical method that I described above?

Comment: **Update**: The list I am trying to access has 56,544 items in it, with more items being added every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Show Data' option normally tries to fetch all the data from the respective SharePoint List or Database.

I can suggest you a workaround solution which might suit you.

While creating a Data View web part, using a list, instead of "Show data" there is another option called "Copy and Modify". While selecting this option, you get a dialog option, to enter a filter criteria for the list to be retrieved. Give a filter criteria that brings you comparatively less number of records. This creates a new list copy, which only has records that is filtered from the main list. Clicking on "Show Data" for this new list should bring you the desired results.

Comment: I have tried that, and the same problem arises. All the options will grey out, and SPD will crash. Any other ideas?

Comment: I was finally able to do the copy and modify technique and eliminated a bunch of columns I wasn't going to use. It switched to the 'Data Source Details' tab and said "The server returned a non-specific error when trying to get the data from the data source... etc. etc." Could this be a server configuration problem?

Comment: Please look into the solutions provided in this blog - http://www.iotap.com/Blog/tabid/673/entryid/69/Getting-rid-of-ldquo-The-server-returned-a-non-specific-error-rdquo-in-SharePoint-Designer.aspx

Answer (score -1):

please use Show Sample Data option.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-sample-data-in-a-data-view-HA010072840.aspx